# Howto solve postMessage from WebView to React Native does not work for Android

Tags: android, react-native

This basic postMessage example works for IOS but does **not work for Android**.

The React Native app on Android fails to receives the post message send from the js code (const simple) injected into the WebView.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    WebView
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
    render() {
        const simple = function() { window.postMessage('my message from Webview to RN');}
        const postMessageCode = '(' + String(simple) + ')();';
        return (
            <WebView
                source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
                injectedJavaScript={postMessageCode}
                onMessage={this.onWebViewMessage}
            />
        );
    }

    onWebViewMessage(event) {
        alert(event);
    }
}
```

This has been tested with:

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.50.4

On:
 - Android emulator version 26.0.0-3833124, Android 7.1.1, API 25
 - Android native device ONE E1005 (One plusX), Android version 6.0.1, API 23

**Who has been able to get postMessage working  (WebView --> RN) on an Android device / emulator or thinks they know how to?**

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue. There seems to be a delay in the Android browser on React Native attaching listeners to postMessage. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11594

I use this little helper on my web pages to get around it:

```
var message = 'some message string';

window.parent.postMessage(message,"*"); 

function whenRNPostMessageReady(cb) {
    if (postMessage.length === 1) cb();
    else setTimeout(function() { whenRNPostMessageReady(cb) }, 100);
}
whenRNPostMessageReady(function() {
    //react native accepts strings only
    window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message),"*");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use WebView ref `postMessage` instead.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    WebView
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
    sendMessage = () => { 
      this.webViewRef.postMessage('my message from Webview to RN');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <WebView
                source={{uri: 'theURL'}}
                ref={(ref) => { this.webViewRef = ref }}
                onMessage={this.onWebViewMessage}
            />
        );
    }

    onWebViewMessage(event) {
        alert(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Juan. Thank you for your reply. Have you tried this with the specs given in the question?